# Appropriate analysis for three different measures of anxiety pre & post intervention

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

My study: To examine whether a self-talk intervention has an effect on anxiety. There are two points of measure, pre and post intervention. Anxiety was measured as Somatic anxiety, Cognitive anxiety and Self-confidence.

Now, I'm reading around and think a paired samples t-test would provide a good comparison of means pre and post intervention, but I would like to examine the effects of individual constructs as well. For example, high self-confidence can lead to lower cognitive anxiety.

I understand I could do a correlation for this, but is there any form of analysis that allows the examination of all this at once? I've tried a repeated measures ANOVA, but the problem is that it groups all my anxiety variables as one whole variable.